# How i can make the 360 Deg rotating slider in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Here is the image for reference Is there any lib. I searched but have not found it.

So once the user clicks on any of the icons that icon will rotate and come to focus
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyzQF.png)

Actually i am looking for slider something like this http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/s3dcar/example2.html

Comment: Actually i am looking for slider something like this http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/s3dcar/example2.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for that. What you're looking for is the [rotate CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate).

So simply add a state that records the clicked property and adds a "rotated" (you likely want to add a [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)) CSS class based on if the component is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  width : 300px;
  position : absolute;
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%;
  transform : translate(-50% , -50%);
  height : 300px;
  background-color : #ccc
  
}

img {
transition : 1s;
width : 100%;
}

div:hover img{
  transform : rotate3d(0 , 1 , 0,180deg)
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://sb.kaleidousercontent.com/67418/800x533/9e7eebd2c6/animals-0b6addc448f4ace0792ba4023cf06ede8efa67b15e748796ef7765ddeb45a6fb-removebg.png" />
</div>
```